Return false does not break the each loop in cypress
This is the code snippet I have
cy.get('[data-testid="userRecords"]')
  .each((record) => {
    if (record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(":enabled")) 
    {
        cy.wrap(record).find('[data-testid="delete"]').click()
        if (someValue == 1) 
        {
            cy.get('[data-testid="test"]').should("be.visible");
        }
        else 
        {
            cy.get('[data-tstid="anotherTest"]').should("be.not.exist")
        }
        return false;
    }

The goal I am trying to achieve here is that if the outer if statement is entered, then I want to break the each loop.
Can someone guide me why I am not able to exit the each loop?

For anyone else who may want to check, each does describe using return false in this way: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early

@Sudipto - what jquery?

how do you know the if (record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(":enabled")) is true and the each keeps iterating?

@user - Your code block ends prematurely...?

Are you sure it's entering the outer if block?

record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(":enabled") is a jQuery expression.

From the documentation that @T.J.Crowder linked to earlier, you can see that after cy.get(selector).each(el => el is a "wrapped jQuery object" (in the comments of the example), (to back up Poodle's assertion).

You could switch to .is(':not([disabled]')) for a better result.
See jQuery - :enabled selector

:enabled selector is subtly different from :not([disabled]).
:enabled selects elements that have their boolean disabled property strictly equal to false

If I boil it down to this test example
HTML
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-testid="userRecords">
      <td data-testid="delete" disabled><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-testid="userRecords">
      <td data-testid="delete" ><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-testid="userRecords">
      <td data-testid="delete"><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Test
cy.get('[data-testid="userRecords"]').each((record, index) => { 

  Cypress.log({ message: `Processing ${index}` })
  console.log(index, ':enabled', record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(":enabled"))
  console.log(index, ':not([disabled]', record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(':not([disabled]'))

  if (record.find('[data-testid="delete"]').is(':not([disabled]')) 
  {
    Cypress.log({ message: `Returning on ${index}` })
    return false;
  }
})

I get an early exit on the 2nd element, skipping the 3rd element.


